# Colourise rows of a table depending on a cell content

Tags: tables, color, tabulary

I looked around a bit but could not find an appropriate answer. I have a table in which I want to colourise rows green if there is a checkmark in the  second cell, otherwise leave it white. I would also love it to be automatically, i.e. if I write `\checkmark` (or a similar, self defined command), that the rows turn green automatically.

I experimented a bit with the `colortbl`-package and the `\rowcolor{green}`-command, but it gave me error messages and removed some of the lines in the table, furthermore, it would not be automatically.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Number & Active? & Some more content... \\ \hline
        001 & \checkmark & ... \\ \hline
        002 & \checkmark & ... \\ \hline
        003 &  & ... \\ \hline
        004 &  & ... \\ \hline
        005 & \checkmark & ... \\ \hline
        006 &  & ... \\ \hline
        ... &  & ...
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: example_rows]

Here I want to colourise the first, second and fifth row in green.

Thank you!

Comment: Are the numbers in the first column progressive or should they be input separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is possible to test for the presence of checkmark in the column, it is imho easier to simply mark up the active rows:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse,array}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \g_car_active_bool
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \caractiverow {}
{
 \rowcolor{green}
 \bool_gset_true:N \g_car_active_bool
}

\NewDocumentCommand \carcheckmark {}
 {
  \bool_if:NT \g_car_active_bool
   {
    \checkmark
   }
  \bool_gset_false:N \g_car_active_bool 

 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|>{\carcheckmark}c|c|}
        \hline
               Number & Active? & Some more content... \\ \hline
\caractiverow     001 &  & ... \\ \hline
\caractiverow     002 &  & ... \\ \hline
                  003 &  & ... \\ \hline
                  004 &  & ... \\ \hline
\caractiverow     005 &  & ... \\ \hline
                  006 &  & ... \\ \hline
        ... &  & ...
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the column in the first row are progressive, so we can hook to this by defining a `\newrow` command that checks if it is followed by `\checkmark`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcounter{rowcount}
\renewcommand{\therowcount}{%
  \ifnum\value{rowcount}<100 0\fi
  \ifnum\value{rowcount}<10 0\fi
  \arabic{rowcount}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newrow}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\checkmark
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\rowcolor{green}\stepcounter{rowcount}\therowcount & \checkmark}%
  {\stepcounter{rowcount}\therowcount &&}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setcounter{rowcount}{0}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Number & Active? & Some more content... \\
\hline
\newrow\checkmark & ... \\
\hline
\newrow\checkmark & ... \\
\hline
\newrow           & ... \\
\hline
\newrow           & ... \\
\hline
\newrow\checkmark & ... \\
\hline
\newrow           & ... \\
\hline
\newrow           & ... \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can change the definition of `\newrow` into

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newrow}[1]{%
  \ifx#1*%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\rowcolor{green}\stepcounter{rowcount}\therowcount & \checkmark}%
  {\stepcounter{rowcount}\therowcount &&}%
}
\makeatother
```

so the input may be simpler:

```
\setcounter{rowcount}{0}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Number & Active? & Some more content... \\
\hline
\newrow* & ... \\
\hline
\newrow* & ... \\
\hline
\newrow  & ... \\
\hline
\newrow  & ... \\
\hline
\newrow* & ... \\
\hline
\newrow  & ... \\
\hline
\newrow  & ... \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```